# Email push notification for new message in c#

Tags: c#, email, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, pop3

I am using IBM lotus note web mail server and looking for a solution on [this](http://boltware.in/images/question.png) diagram. My program is written in C# language with [OpenPop.NET](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hpop/). Is there an efficient way to monitor new email received in inbox instead of running a schedule job every 1 minute like new mail notification or some signalR type of? I believe that connecting to web mail box again and again every 1 minute is not a good practice. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no published API for push notifications of message delivery from the IBM Domino server.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you can modify the design of the mail files, you could write "before/after new mail arrives" Notes agents. That could send out the notifications, deposit the info in another db, or post it to url. Does not feel to be an extremely efficient solution, but probably better than intense polling of Domino server.

You probably want this to happen just while user has "connected" to his mailbox, not always process all thousands of mail files? This means the agent on Domino should have access to the info if the user is connected or not. In short - a bunch of code on Domino server that makes one think if the whole app would better be Domino based web app (depends of course on what else the app does).